# Importing database to ms sql server

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database, phpmyadmin

I am trying to import my database from phpmyadmin to sql server, but getting this error when I am trying to execute the sql code to create it:

```
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 10
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IF'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 10
Incorrect syntax near 'nih_bw'.
Msg 911, Level 16, State 1, Line 11
Database 'nih_bw' does not exist. Make sure that the name is entered correctly.
```

This is the database:

```
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;

--
-- Database: "nih_bw"
--
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS "nih_bw" DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci;
USE nih_bw;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table "emps"
--

CREATE TABLE "emps" (
  "id" int NOT NULL,
  "user_name" varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  "first_name" varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  "last_name" varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  "email" varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  "password" varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  "user_type" char(5) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY ("id")
);

--
-- Dumping data for table "emps"
--

SET IDENTITY_INSERT "emps" ON ;
INSERT INTO "emps" ("id", "user_name", "first_name", "last_name", "email", "password", "user_type") VALUES
(1, 'root', 'root', 'root', 'root@gmail.com', 'hei123', 'user');

SET IDENTITY_INSERT "emps" OFF;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table "measurements"
--

CREATE TABLE "measurements" (
  "id" int NOT NULL,
  "title" varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY ("id")
);

--
-- Dumping data for table "measurements"
--

SET IDENTITY_INSERT "measurements" ON ;
INSERT INTO "measurements" ("id", "title") VALUES
(1, 'T_Badende_per_Time'),
(2, 'T_Temperatur'),
(3, 'T_Luft_Temperatur'),
(4, 'M_Fritt_Klor'),
(5, 'M_Bundet_Klor'),
(6, 'M_Total_Klor'),
(7, 'M_PH'),
(8, 'M_Auto_Klor'),
(9, 'M_Auto_PH'),
(10, 'M_Redox'),
(11, 'O_Vannbalanse'),
(12, 'O_Alakalitet'),
(13, 'O_Hardhet'),
(14, 'O_Natrium_Bk'),
(15, 'O_Kals_Klor'),
(16, 'O_Sjokklor'),
(17, 'O_Fellingsmiddel'),
(18, 'O_Sirkulasjonsmengde'),
(19, 'O_Filtertrykk'),
(20, 'O_Spyl_Av_Filter'),
(21, 'O_Vannforbruk'),
(22, 'O_Slamsuging'),
(23, 'O_Harsil'),
(24, 'O_Ren_Utj_Tank');

SET IDENTITY_INSERT "measurements" OFF;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table "measure_routine"
--

CREATE TABLE "measure_routine" (
  "routine_id" int NOT NULL,
  "measure_id" int NOT NULL,
  "pool_id" int DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY ("routine_id","measure_id"),
  KEY "pool_id" ("pool_id"),
  KEY "link3" ("measure_id")
);

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table "pools"
--

CREATE TABLE "pools" (
  "id" int NOT NULL,
  "name" varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY ("id")
);

--
-- Dumping data for table "pools"
--

SET IDENTITY_INSERT "pools" ON ;
INSERT INTO "pools" ("id", "name") VALUES
(1, 'Hovedbasseng'),
(2, 'Plaskebasseng'),
(99, 'Svommehall');

SET IDENTITY_INSERT "pools" OFF;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table "routines"
--

CREATE TABLE "routines" (
  "id" int NOT NULL,
  "date" datetime NOT NULL,
  "time" time NOT NULL,
  "value" varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  "emp_id" int NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY ("id"),
  KEY "emp_id" ("emp_id")
);

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table "tasks"
--

CREATE TABLE "tasks" (
  "id" int NOT NULL,
  "title" varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY ("id")
);

--
-- Dumping data for table "tasks"
--

SET IDENTITY_INSERT "tasks" ON ;
INSERT INTO "tasks" ("id", "title") VALUES
(40, 'D_Slamsuge_Pl_Bass'),
(41, 'D_Filter_Rens'),
(42, 'D_Bypass_Pl_Bass'),
(43, 'D_Vaske_Gulv_CM'),
(44, 'D_Garderobe_0730'),
(45, 'D_Garderobe_Dag'),
(46, 'D_Male_Temp_Just'),
(47, 'D_Vaske_Pl_Bass'),
(48, 'D_Vaske_H_Bass'),
(49, 'D_Renhold_Av_Wc'),
(50, 'D_Ettersyn_Utst_Skap'),
(51, 'D_Handicap_Heis'),
(52, 'D_Ettersyn_solarier'),
(53, 'D_Vannprove_0745'),
(54, 'D_Vannprover_1100'),
(55, 'D_Vannprover_1400'),
(56, 'D_Enkle_Vedliks_Oppg'),
(57, 'D_Sjekk_Skiftplan'),
(58, 'K_Oppdatere_Seg_IkkeUtf'),
(59, 'K_Vannprover_1700'),
(60, 'K_Vannprover_2000'),
(61, 'K_Vaske_Pl_Bass'),
(62, 'K_Vaske_H_Bass'),
(63, 'K_Sla_Av_Bypass'),
(64, 'K_Ettersyn_Materiell'),
(65, 'K_Ettersyn_Solarier'),
(66, 'K_Ettersyn_Sal_4'),
(67, 'K_Runde_Gard_Kveld'),
(68, 'K_Runde_Gard_For_Steng'),
(69, 'K_Enkle_Vedlik_Oppg'),
(70, 'K_Rullestolheis_lading'),
(71, 'K_Etterfylle_Skoposer'),
(72, 'K_Skap_Lases'),
(73, 'K_Sjekk_Skiftplan'),
(74, 'K_Rydd_Tribune'),
(75, 'K_Slamsug_H_Bass'),
(76, 'K_Stenge_Prosedyre'),
(77, 'K_Beskjed_H_Vakt'),
(78, 'K_Timeteller'),
(79, 'C_Timeteller'),
(80, 'C_AllRent'),
(81, 'C_Grovrent_Ekstra'),
(82, 'C_Ren_Opplos_Tank'),
(83, 'C_Ren_Opps_Tank'),
(84, 'C_Ren_Flott_gitter'),
(85, 'C_Ren_Opplos_Filter'),
(86, 'C_Ren_Nal'),
(87, 'C_Kontr_Slang_Tank'),
(88, 'C_Kont_Ren_KostPad');

SET IDENTITY_INSERT "tasks" OFF;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table "task_routine"
--

CREATE TABLE "task_routine" (
  "routine_id" int NOT NULL,
  "task_id" int NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY ("routine_id","task_id"),
  KEY "link6" ("task_id")
);

--
-- Constraints for dumped tables
--

--
-- Constraints for table "measure_routine"
--
ALTER TABLE "measure_routine"
  ADD CONSTRAINT "link2" FOREIGN KEY ("routine_id") REFERENCES "routines" ("id") ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  ADD CONSTRAINT "link3" FOREIGN KEY ("measure_id") REFERENCES "measurements" ("id") ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;

--
-- Constraints for table "routines"
--
ALTER TABLE "routines"
  ADD CONSTRAINT "link1" FOREIGN KEY ("emp_id") REFERENCES "emps" ("id") ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;

--
-- Constraints for table "task_routine"
--
ALTER TABLE "task_routine"
  ADD CONSTRAINT "link5" FOREIGN KEY ("routine_id") REFERENCES "routines" ("id") ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  ADD CONSTRAINT "link6" FOREIGN KEY ("task_id") REFERENCES "tasks" ("id") ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

Comment: Ok, let me clarifty that. YOu made an export of a MySql database and think it will magically import into a SQL Server? Did it ever occur to you that every sql dialect is different. Bad news: it is. Sadly sort of. YOu will have to clean up your generated SQL. By hand. Or use another tool to generate the scripts.

Comment: Yes, I made a export from phpmyadmin in sql by chosing Database system or older MySQL server to maximize output compatibility with: mssql in the options.

Comment: If it was supposed to create an SQL server compatible script, it seems to have failed. `CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS nih_bw` won't work for example, so you won't get a database to start with.

Comment: It was supposed to maximiuze - not to be total ;)

Comment: @TomTom True, but I'd still call failing on the second line of the script and not even creating a database somewhat of a fail ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to take a look at your very first statement where you are trying to create a database , Start you script with something as follows

```
USE master;
GO

IF DB_ID('dbname') IS NOT NULL
  DROP DATABASE nih_bw
GO

CREATE DATABASE [nih_bw] ON  PRIMARY 
( NAME = N'nih_bw'
 , FILENAME = N'C:\Path_mdf_File\nih_bw.mdf' , SIZE = 5120000KB , FILEGROWTH = 1024KB )
 LOG ON 
( NAME = N'nih_bw_log'
  , FILENAME = N'D:\Path_For_ldf_File\nih_bw_log.ldf' , SIZE = 512000KB , FILEGROWTH = 10%)
 COLLATE SQL_SwedishStd_Pref_CP1_CI_AS
GO


USE [nih_bw]
GO


/* Now from here continue with rest of your script */
```